# media query hide/show div

Tags: css, media-queries, media

I was able to get this to work showing the Left Ctr Right columns on desktop and R only on mobile. What I'm trying to do now, unsuccessfully, is add a 4th col which will only show on mobile. So L,C,R on desktop, 4th col only on mobile. I tried having the 4th col in the same div but while it would hide on desktop, it does not show on mobile. So I've created new div id: "mobSlide" to contain 4th col and I hide/show the "mobSlide" div, but that is not working either. Any thoughts?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="slideshowBL"><img src="../images/slideshow/pouch.jpg" />
</div>
</div>

<div id="centerCol">
<div class="slideshowCT"><img src="../images/slideshow/basso56.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="slideshowCB"><img src="../images/slideshow/bruschetta.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="slideshowR" id="rightCol"><img src="../images/slideshow/kettle.jpg" />
</div>

<div id="mobSlide">
<div class="slideshowR" id="rightCol2"><img src="../images/slideshow/kettle.jpg" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS mobile:
    #leftCol, #centerCol, #rightCol {
          display: none;
      } 
      #leftCol {
          width: 205px;
          float: left;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }

```
  #centerCol {
      width: 150px;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 10px;
  }

  #rightCol {
      width: 250px;
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 10px;
  }

   #mobSlide {
      }
```

CSS desktop:

```
  #leftCol {
      display: block;
  }

  #centerCol {
      display: block;
  }
   #rightCol {
       display:block;
  }

   #mobSlide { display:none;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding media queries to your help;
If you know on what resolution that div should show up, try something like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px){
    #mobSlider{
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Update: Heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZZh8/) sample to illustrate that example(shrink and expand the screen)

Comment: Still not showing in mobile. Here is the site:
http://gbetza.mydomain.com/webservice2/test/Basso56/test/
and CSS:
http://gbetza.mydomain.com/webservice2/test/Basso56/test/css/style.css
It works fine in dreamweaver but not in browser or mobile.

Answer (score -1):

With CSS mobile change:

```
#mobSlide {
    }
```

To:

```
#mobSlide {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thank you. waiting for server to update to check. it works in dreamweaver without that display, but maybe the browser needs that?

Comment: hey Jake, I didn't do that. Not sure what happened. How do I undo?